# Crawl/scrape websites/webpages containing a specific text, with no prior information about any such websites/webpages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, nutch

I used nutch and scrapy.  They need seed URLs to crawl.  That means, one should be already aware of the websites/webpages which would contain the text that is being searched for.

My case is different, I do not have the prior information about the websites/webpages which contain the text I am searching for.  So I won't be able to use seed URLs to be crawled by tools such as nutch and scrapy.

Is there a way to crawl websites/webpages for a given text, without knowing any websites/webpages that would possibly contain that text?

Answer (score 1):

You could parse [the commoncrawl dataset](https://commoncrawl.org/). It contains billions of webpages. Their site contains examples on how to do it with MapReduce.
Other than that any web crawler needs to have some starting point.

Comment: @ Julien Nioche : That is a good piece of info.  You are most possibly right.  Crawl needs a starting point.  All the crawlers available free would need a seed to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview?csw=1) for 100 free queries/day. The search results will be in JSON format, which you can use to feed the links to your scraper.

Comment: I have been using this method you mentioned above, at the time of posting this query.  Is there any other way that we can do it other than relying on Google? Appreciate your response, thank you!!

Comment: Other than creating your own Google? I guess you could do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4940212/5247482, and just pick a random website as a seed to get it started..

Comment: @ Jon : The query and the solutions in the link provided are related to focused crawl on a specific website and the links available there. I lately understood that, crawls need one seed URL at least.  In other words, (a straightforward) crawl without seed URL(s) might not be possible.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: If there is a way to do a crawl without a seed URL, I don't know about it. But that's not necessarily bad -- just pick a good starting point. If you were taking a journey, you would need to start **somewhere**... but you could still end up anywhere. If don't want to have to pick a seed URL, then you could you could try randomly generating URL names ...

Comment: @ Jon : Well I can start somewhere but I want to crawl the most appropriate webpages, that means out of say 100 pages crawled, 80 to 85% need to be relevant. Else a vast majority of the pages crawled would be of no use. Again, that is the reason I went back to Google. Back to square one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use requests module to get data.

Here in below example I am getting data from all sites having "pizza" word in those.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.google.com/search'
my_headers = { 'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/11.0' }
payload = { 'q' : 'pizza', 'start' : '0' }
r = requests.get( url, params = payload, headers = my_headers )
```

You can use BeautifulSoup library to extract any type of information from retrieved data (HTML data)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup( r.text, 'html.parser' )
```

Now if you want text data you can use this function

```
soup.getText()
```

Comment: I agree with your solution on fetching the text data from the crawled web pages.  But this approach still uses google search and then crawl the resulting web pages. I am looking out for a way without using any of these search engines. Is there a way out? Thanks for the response.